# помогите перевести код с c++ на c#

Tags: c#, c++

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

struct MyFIFO{
    int val;  
    int size; 
    MyFIFO *Head,*Tail,*Next; 
        void Add(const int x); 
        void Show();
        void Del();
};

void MyFIFO::Add(int x){
    static int count=0;
/////////////////////////////////////////////
    MyFIFO *temp = new MyFIFO;  
    Next=temp->Head;            
    temp->val=x;                
    if (Head!=NULL){            
        Tail->Next=temp;   
        Tail=temp;          
    } else Head=Tail=temp;      
////////////////////////////////////////////
    count++;    
    size=count;

}

void MyFIFO::Show(){
    MyFIFO *temp=Head;  //Получаем адрес начала очереди

    while (temp!=Tail->Next){            //Пока адрес указателя не совпадет со следующим элементом за хвостом очереди
        cout<<temp->val<<"   "<<"\n";       //Будем выбирать элементы, использя указатель temp
        temp=temp->Next;             //Как только выбрали элемент, переходим по новому адресу к следующему элементу

    }   
}

void MyFIFO::Del(){     

    MyFIFO *temp=new MyFIFO;
    int count=0;

    while (temp!=Tail){
        temp=Head;//Нашли текущее начало очереди и запомнили адрес в сторонюю переменую
        Head=Head->Next; //Сместили фактическое начало на адрес следующего поступившего элемента
           cout<<"Udalena swiaz s:  "<<temp->val<<"\n";  //Для наглядности
        delete temp;  //Очистили связь
    }   
}


int main(){


    MyFIFO Q1;  //Объявили переменную типа нашей очереди FIFO (имя структуры)
    Q1.Head=NULL;  //Обозначили что голова пустая, ибо очередь пуста (можно в конструкторе)
    Q1.Add(100);   //Добавляем элементы
    Q1.Add(200);
    Q1.Add(300);

    Q1.Show();  //Показываем нашу очередь
    Q1.Del();   //Очищаем память

    cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: мне кажется есть куча примеров реализации очереди на c#, Вам нужен именно конкретно текущий код?

Comment: нет, не обязательно этот, но я не хочу копировать сложные коды, хотелось бы разобраться самому

Comment: гуглу уже пора добавить в Google Translate перевод с С++ на C# и обратно. Это пользовалось бы куда большим успехом, чем возможность перевода с каталонского на узбекский

Answer (score 2):

Вот переписал на шарпе (если что - это первая моя программа на нем за последние лет 10). Старался переписать так, что бы сохранить main по максимуму. То, что в коде нет связанного списка - это нормально. Но и плюсовый код также жуткий:)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class MyFIFO
{
    private Queue myQ;

    public MyFIFO() {
        myQ = new Queue();
    }
    public void Add(int x) {
        myQ.Enqueue(x);
    }

    public void Show() {
        foreach ( int x in myQ )
          Console.Write( "    {0}\n", x );
       Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void Del() {
        myQ.Clear();
    }
}

public class Test
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        MyFIFO Q1 = new MyFIFO();  //Объявили переменную типа нашей очереди FIFO (имя структуры)
        //Q1.Head=NULL;  //вот тут лучше было сделать в конструкторе изначально.
        Q1.Add(100);   //Добавляем элементы
        Q1.Add(200);
        Q1.Add(300);

        Q1.Show();  //Показываем нашу очередь
        Q1.Del();   //Очищаем память
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться)

Comment: наверное лучше `Queue<int>` не уверен, что сейчас `foreach` отработает

Comment: http://ideone.com/WkN9hi

Comment: интересно, а если бы в очереди уже был добавлен не _int_?

Comment: Вам никто не мешает проэкспериментировать:)

Comment: _Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type._, что в принципе и логично :-)

Comment: не мог ли кто-нибудь помочь написать этот код, для winforms

Comment: сам класс MyFIFO уже "winforms совместимый". А нарисовать форму и набросать туда кнопок - это тема отдельного вопроса и изучения.

Comment: Вот интересно, за что ответ начали активно минусовать?